# can't for loop in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Im trying to loop in ejs template, but unexpectedly keep getting these error

In normal javascript

```
var three = 3;

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i+= 3) {
    console.log("i is " + i);
    for (var j = i; j < three; j++) {
        console.log("j is " + j);
    }
    three += 3;
}
```

In javascript it works just fine.

The problem is in ejs, I have two versions that I tried, both of them are not working

**First Attempt**

```
<% var three = 3;
    for(var i=0; i < jobs.length; i+=3)  { %>

    <div class="row stylish-panel">

      <% for (var j = i; j < three; j++) { %>

      <div class="col-md-4">
      <h4><%= jobs[j].title %></h4>

        <div>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/1/" alt="Texto Alternativo" class="img-circle img-thumbnail">
        </div>
      </div>
      <% } three += 3;%>
      </div>
    <% } %>
```

**Second attempt**

```
<% for(var i=0, three=3; i < jobs.length; i+=3, three+=3)  { %>

    <div class="row stylish-panel">

      <% for (var j = i; j < three; j++) { %>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4><%= jobs[j].title %></h4>
        <div>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/1/" alt="Texto Alternativo" class="img-circle img-thumbnail">
        </div>
      </div>
      <% } %>
      </div>
    <% } %>
```

It keeps telling that `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`, but if I change `j < three` to `j < 10`, it works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code, `j` also goes out of it's bounds of 10. In the last 4 lines of your output, you get:

```
i is 9
j is 9
j is 10
j is 11
```

The last 2 lines is where the problem is. This can be easily solved in your original, or 'normal' code as you name it:

```
var three = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 3) {
    console.log("i is " + i);
    for (var j = i; j < three && j < 10; j++) {
        console.log("j is " + j);
    }
    three += 3;
}
```

Note that I have added `&& j < 10`. Reworking that in a second attempt, becomes:

```
for (var i = 0, three = 3; i < 10; i += 3, three += 3) {
    console.log("i is " + i);
    for (var j = i; j < three && j < 10; j++) {
        console.log("j is " + j);
    }
}
```

But then further examination shows that variable `three` is not even needed, and you can just use this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 3) {
    console.log("i is " + i);
    for (var j = i; j < i + 3 && j < 10; j++) {
        console.log("j is " + j);
    }
}
```

Still works the same. And then attempting to work that back into your final code:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < jobs.length; i += 3)  { %>
  <div class="row stylish-panel">
  <% for (var j = i; j < i + 3 && j < jobs.length; j++) { %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h4><%= jobs[j].title %></h4>
      <div>
        <img
          src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/1/"
          alt="Texto Alternativo"
          class="img-circle ing-thumbnail"
          />
      </div>
    </div>
  <% } %>
  </div>
<% } %>
```

So apparently you have a solution to arrange things in columns of 3 fitting whatever number of rows are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an index position of "jobs" which is beyond the upper limit. Notice, you are only checking if "i" is less than jobs.length. Since, "three" starts from 3 (and is incremented just like "i"), three (and, consequently j) becomes greater than jobs.length!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my array of objects:

```
    const types = [
      {
        value: "fulltime",
        label: "Fulltime",
      },
      {
        value: "c2c",
        label: "Corp-to-Corp",
      },
      {
        value: "contract",
        label: "Contract (1099)",
      },

      {
        value: "internship",
        label: "Internship",
      },
      {
        value: "parttime",
        label: "Part-time",
      },
    ];
    await ctx.render({ view: "gigs/new" }, { user, token, types });
```

Here is my ejs template using `for..of`

```
    <div class="field">
        <label for="type">Employee Type:</label>
        <ul class="list">
        <% for (let type of types) { %>
            <li>
                <label class="checkbox-label">
                    <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="type"
                        value="<%= type.value %>"
                        class="radio"
                    />
                    <%= type.label %>
                </label>
            </li>
        <% } %>
        </ul>
    </div>
```